# How to show Ckeditor document in read only mode as in edit mode without the editor

Tags: ckeditor

How can I show documents created with Ckeditor in read only so that they as much as possible like in the editing mode but without having to create the editor for each message?

In my project users can send messages to each other among many other things and they create the messages using Ckeditor. I would to render message threads in readonly mode without having to create the Ckeditor for each message. Doing that would be slow and would consume a lot of vertical space. Another problem with that approach is that removing the toolbar removes formatting. I would like to just have the messages in div tags and add a class to them and then include Ckeditor css file. Or also acceptable would be to have one element with certain class whose children would get the Ckeditor styles. Before putting the messages in the html response I do whitelisting on the server so the docs are safe to put inside for example a div tag.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by wrapping the message in an iframe element and added dynamically a style element that links to the Ckeditor style sheet. Now the message gets Ckeditor styles and I don't need to create the editor at all in the read only state and the rest of my page unaffected by the Ckeditor styles.